A square matrix $A$ is similar to $A^*$ if and only if $A$ is similar to a real matrix
How can I prove that a square matrix $A$ is similar to $A^*$ if and only if $A$ is similar to a real matrix? Here, $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and $A^*$ means the conjugate transpose of $A$.
I read it in Matrix Theory, but in the textbook it only illustrates the $2\times 2$ situation and doesn't give any proof. It just proves that the statement $A$ is similar to $A^*$ is equivalent to the Jordan blocks of the non-real eigenvalues of $A$ occurring in conjugate pairs. I don't know how to get this equivalent to the statement that $A$ is similar to a real matrix.

My first idea would be to check their nullifying polynomials and their roots, you should take inspiration from the case $A=A^*$. Then when you find that its eigenvalues are real you can use some very convenient theorem by Jordan

@julio_es_sui_glace However since the Jordan block of $A$ occurs in conjugate pairs,the nullfying polynomials may have factors like $(\lambda -\lambda_1)(\lambda -\overline \lambda_1)$,which is an unfactorizable quadratic term in $\mathbb{R}$

Yeah but that’s a first step. You can also use Frobenius decomposition it could work directly

Or take inspiration from it

This can be done fairly explicitly. Once you know that non-real eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs with Jordan blocks of the same size, they can be arranged to be one after the other via conjugation by a permutation (which is a similarity). So that part of the Jordan form looks like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}J_k(\lambda)&0\\0&J_k(\overline\lambda)\end{bmatrix}.
$$
And this is similar to a real matrix because
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}I_k&\!\!\!-iI_k\\iI_k&\!\!\!-I_k\end{bmatrix}\!\!\!\begin{bmatrix}J_k(\lambda)&\!\!\!0\\0&\!\!\!J_k(\overline\lambda)\end{bmatrix}\!\!\!\begin{bmatrix}I_k&\!\!\!-iI_k\\iI_k&\!\!\!-I_k\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\!\!&\!\!= \!\!\frac12\begin{bmatrix}J_k(\lambda)+J_k(\overline\lambda)&\!\!\!\!\!\!-i\big(J_k(\lambda)-J_k(\overline\lambda)\big) \\i\big(J_k(\lambda)-J_k(\overline\lambda)\big)& \!\!\!\!\!\!J_k(\lambda)+J_k(\overline\lambda)\end{bmatrix}\\[0.2cm]
&=\begin{bmatrix}J_k(\operatorname{Re}\lambda)&\operatorname{Im}\lambda\,I_k\\- \operatorname{Im}\lambda\,I_k&J_k(\operatorname{Re}\lambda)\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
is real.

This answer is sort of what julio_es_sui_glace was hinting at in the comments with the Frobenius/rational canonical form.
So you have that $A$ and $A^\ast$ are similar if and only if the Jordan blocks of the non-real eigenvalues of $A$ come in conjugate pairs with equal block size. Suppose we have a pair of $k \times k$ Jordan blocks for non-real eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\overline{\lambda}$. The goal is to show that there is a $2k \times 2k$ real matrix with Jordan canonical form consisting of these two Jordan blocks together. Note that the minimal (and characteristic) polynomial of this $2k \times 2k$ matrix is $p(x) = (x - \lambda)^k (x - \overline{\lambda})^k$, which is a polynomial with real coefficients. We will basically use this polynomial to construct the desired matrix.
Consider the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of polynomials of degree at most $2k - 1$, which has a basis $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{2k-1}\}$. Let $T$ be a linear map on this space defined on the basis by $T(x^j) = x^{j+1}$ for $0 \leq j \leq 2k - 2$ and $T(x^{2k-1}) = x^{2k} - p(x)$. Note that $p(x)$ is a degree $2k$ polynomial with leading coefficient $1$, so $T(x^{2k-1})$ is still in the vector space. Moreover, the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is real. By construction, $p(T) = 0$ and $f(T) \neq 0$ for all polynomials $f$ of degree at most $2k - 1$, so $p$ is the minimal (and characteristic) polynomial of $T$. It follows that $T$ has only two distinct eigenvalues (including multiplicity) so the Jordan canonical form of $T$ is two $k \times k$ Jordan blocks each with eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\overline{\lambda}$.
Conversely, let $A$ be similar to a real matrix $B$. $B$ is similar to $B^T$ (since Jordan blocks are similar to their transpose). Since $B^T = B^\ast$, the first part implies that the non-real Jordan blocks of $B$ (and thus $A$) come in conjugate pairs.

I get $f(T)\neq 0$ for all polynomials $f$ whose degree less than $2k$,but how to get $p(T)=0$?It is hard to calculate it.

Yeah, the notation is a bit weird. First, for any $0 \leq j \leq 2k - 1$ you have that $p(T) = p(T) T^j(1) = T^j p(T)$ so it suffices to prove that $p(T) = 0$. The largest degree $T$ in $p(T)$ gives $T^{2k}(1) = T(x^{2k-1}) = (x^{2k} - p(x))$ (basically $-p(x)$ without the $x^{2k}$ term). All other terms are more straightforward, they give $(p(x) - x^{2k})$ ($p(x)$ without the $x^{2k}$ term). Add these two together to get $0$.

Oh,I get it.Thanks a lot!
